# Logging user's device details in DJango admin

Tags: python, django

How to log the login user's device, os, ipaddress, location etc. in Django?

1. Is there any library available for this?

Answer (score 1):

Sure there is. Try Django axes (https://github.com/jazzband/django-axes).
With this, you can:

1. See logs of every login from Django admin panel (Axes logs)
2. You can control user login failure and much more.

Comment: Thanks!! It works for the ipaddress and all but how to get the location?

Comment: If you have the IP address, in a sense you have the location too. But I think you want to know the exact GPS location, right? In this case, you have to do some JavaSript at your login page to get the GEO location from the browser and then send the location data in the login request. Save the data from there. Google Geolocation API will help you in this regard.